# How to select unique values from a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I had tried using the the below query but couldn't retrive the distinct values of the column `status_id`.

```
select distinct status_id, schedule_id, cassay_id, time_of_day,
                days, notify_to_addresses, active FROM ordertest
```

The purpose of the the above query is to filter the table to get the unique value of the column '`status_id`' at the same time it needs to fetch values for all columns present in the table. So that my final table will consist of the distinct values of `status_id` and their corresponding other values.

Comment: `distinct` applies to all columns in the select, not just the first column.

Comment: If there are multiple occurences of `status_id` and you want only one occurrence to appear, how do you choose which row to use for the remaining columns?

Comment: is it possible for me to filter just for the first cloumn alone...

Comment: Please provider some example data you have, and some output you want to see. If you want it as I interpret it, you'll see it cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

This query *will* return unique status_id's, but only if the combination of those status_id and each of those other fields is unique too. You can select the unique status_id's, but you cannot return all values of the other fields if there's more than one combination for each status_id.

[edit]

If you want only the first record for each status:

```
select 
  status_id, schedule_id, cassay_id, time_of_day, days, notify_to_addresses, active 
from
  (select 
    row_number() over (partition by status_id order by 1) as number, 
    status_id, schedule_id, cassay_id, time_of_day, days, notify_to_addresses, active 
  FROM ordertest)
where
  number = 1
```

Instead of `row_number`, `dense_rank` and `rank` are used as well for different kinds of numbering, but in this case you really do want a single row, and row_number will suffice.

Not sure `order by` is mandatory. If not, you can leave it out. If it is, you can specify a dummy value or specify a specific field that you want to use as 'the first row'. For example, spedify `order by schedule_id` to return the lowest schedule_id for each status_id.

Comment: A reasonable attempt given that the request is impossible to fulfill as stated.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH DISTINCT_STATUS
AS
(
-- this one will query distinct status id values
   select DISTINCT status_id FROM ordertest
)
-- this query will give extra information in that rows.
select distinct T.status_id, T.schedule_id, T.cassay_id, T.time_of_day,
            T.days, T.notify_to_addresses, T.active 
FROM ordertest T 
INNER JOIN 
DISTINCT_STATUS DS
ON DS.status_id = T.status_id
```

Answer (score -2):

`DISTINCT` works for each row, other fields are not same for all distinct `status_id`, so you can not use DISTINCT.

Use `GROUP BY`, and use Group functions (`MAX,MIN,WM_CONCAT` **WHAT YOU NEED**) for other Columns.

OR use `subqueries` by `primary key` for each column.

Comment: This is wrong. If you use `min`, you get the lowest value. That means you can get a schedule_id that doesn't belong to the same record as the cassay_id you get in the next record. Very unpredictable. Use analytical functions to generate a numbering and filter out any subsequent records.